# Взаимодействие с виджетами пока открыт диалог

Tags: java, android, dialog

Нужно както сделать так,чтобы пользователь мог взаимодействовать с элементами которые находятся в активити,пока открыт диалог...тоесть например нажать на кнопку...или продвинуть seekbar...вообше что угодно...
Это возможно?

Comment: Да, используя регистрацию слушателей в ваш объект диалога